# URL Scheme doesn't always call function

Tags: ios, swift, url

I have an app on the App Store which is a utility for my business. I am receiving feedback from people that when they fill out a form on a webpage which then opens a URL scheme registered in my app, they receive a dialog that says "Open app in APP_NAME", they press open which then takes them back to the app. I then have a function that is meant to be called once the app is opened from a URL scheme. Only about 50% of my users have said this function is being called?? Why might this be?? Its working for some people but not others. Ive tested it myself across different versions of iOS and different devices and it works everytime.

Here is the app delegate method that my function is inside:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

   //Do more stuff......

}
```

I also have the function inside a Scene Delegate function:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
   //Do more stuff.....
}
```

Any insight to why only some users may be experiencing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentaion [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app):

> If your app has opted into Scenes, and your app is not running, the system delivers the URL to the scene(*:willConnectTo:options:) delegate method after launch, and to scene(*:openURLContexts:) when your app opens a URL while running or suspended in memory.

As per the above statement you must handle case when the target app (means your app) isn't running to take necessary actions.

So Try writing the method: scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)

Hope this helps !!!